# jmeter to issue http request based on response

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm using Jmeter for my API testing using various http requests and various samplers to validate them. Now, I'm writing test for another http request. In this test,the steps are:

1. Issue a http request. Handle response.
2. using xpath xtractor, I'm extracting the response and storing URL in another variable(store_url).
3. If variable has a URL, repeat step-1. 
   This loops has to be repeated until no value is stored in (store_URL).

There is not definite number, how many time the loop has to be repeated. It is based on store_url is empty or not.
How can I achieve this in jmeter? I know step-1 and step-2. But I'm looking how to repeat step-1 and step-2. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a jmeter variable loopCount to 1 for init value,
move your step 1 and 2 into a loop controller,
set to loop count to ${loopCount}

in your step 2,
increase loopCount if store_url is found after you finish xpath xtractor

Comment: I got a solution before I checked for any replies. Anyways, Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your points 1 and 2 under [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)
2. Use `${__javaScript(vars.get("store_URL") != null)}` as While Controller's Condition

In condition [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function is used to check `store_URL` variable value.

- if `store_URL` variable is set (has any value) - everything under the While Controller will start over
- if `store_URL` variable becomes null - the look will break
- `vars` - is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables

See [Using JMeter Functions](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743668-using-jmeter-functions---part-ii) article for more detailed information on __javaScript and other useful functions